# how to execute multiple insert statements from HANA at once

Tags: hana

I am having a file `file.txt` which consists of millions of insert commands like below:

```
    "INSERT INTO T (id, serial)  VALUES (0, ARRAY (1) );"
    "INSERT INTO T (id, serial)  VALUES (1, ARRAY (1, 2) );" 
    "INSERT INTO T (id, serial)  VALUES (2, ARRAY (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) );" 
    "INSERT INTO T (id, serial)  VALUES (3, ARRAY (1, 2) ); "
    "INSERT INTO T (id, serial)  VALUES (4, ARRAY (1, 2, 3) );"
.....
.....
.....
```

I want to execute them in HANA using hdbsql or Studio. But how to execute them from the file? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, the commands shouldn't be enclosed in quotation marks.

Then you can either just run the file as-is in HANA studio (only a good idea if your file is not actually MILLIONS of files, since HANA studio parses the SQL commands first and likely will stall, when there are too many), or you run it via `hdbsql` with the `-I` option:

`hdbsql -U <your secure store logon key here> -I insert.sql`

Thinking about it, the latter method would be the one I would likely go for.